# Migrate only published with images in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, migration

I would like to migrate my Wordpress, but I would only want the posts and the images. Nothing about the configuration, nor pluggins, nor the pages.

Comment: What did you try and it didn't work so far? What is the format you are looking to export to? You need to be more specific

Comment: I want to export with the wordpress but don't export the header images. With a plugin I can´t find any that do the export of only post with images

Answer (score 0):

Export posts with images. Install new wordpress and import export-xml file. http://take.ms/vAQoI

Comment: With this solition the header images don't export

Comment: @keznow try to use olugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-export/ and https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/